# how to add a header to a file visual basic

Tags: vba

I have the following code and need to write a header into the file. I am not sure how i go about adding the code so that i can write a header to the file.

My code is as follows:-

```
   Private Enum eCommaSemiColon
     Comma = 0
     Semicolon = 1
    End Enum

   Dim lFile As Long
   Dim lRow As Long
   Dim s As String
   Dim lCounter As Long

   If Me.CurrentInterval = 1 And Me.CurrentTrial = 1 Then
     lFile = FreeFile
      Open Me.FileName.Value For Output As #lFile
       For lRow = 0 To Me.FileContents.Count - 1
        Select Case Me.CommaOrSemiColon.Value
            Case eCommaSemicolon.Comma
                For lCounter = 0 To Me.NoOfColumns.Value - 1
                    If lCounter = 0 Then
                        s = Me.FileContents.Get(lRow, 0)
                    Else
                        s = s & "," & Me.FileContents.Get(lRow, lCounter)
                    End If
                Next
                Print #lFile, s

    Case eCommaSemicolon.Semicolon
                For lCounter = 0 To Me.NoOfColumns.Value - 1
                    If lCounter = 0 Then
                            s = Replace(CStr(Me.FileContents.Get(lRow, 0)), ".", ",")
                           Else
                            s = s & ";" & Replace(CStr(Me.FileContents.Get(lRow, lCounter)), ".", ",")
                    End If
                    Next
                    Print #lFile, s
                Case Else
          End Select
        Next
     Close #lFile
    Else
    End If
```

Comment: This is either not VBA, or it is incomplete code. What the heck is `Me`? And what is `eCommaSemicolon` object, etc.?  Further, describe your desired output **and** how the current output is not satisfactory.  What is a "header"? Where do you want it and how formatted, etc.?

Comment: It VB code thank you very much and yes there is a bit missing the Private Enum ecommaSemicolon which relates to the bit you don't get. Maybe before down voting ask for further clarification, all I want to understand is before I write my output how do I write the header into the file.

Comment: This code will not compile on **anyone** else's computer unless you provide more information, specifically what is `Me` and its child objects (`.FileContents`, etc.), what is the `eCommaSemiColon` object, etc.

Comment: What I am saying is that unless you can provide a [minimum, self-contained, complete & verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it may not be possible to assist you.

Comment: OK I fixed that, your code was not properly formatted in the question. That part is clear. Now, what is `Me` and all of the child objects associated with `Me`?  Is this in a `UserForm`? What application are you working in (Excel, Access, something else?) etc.

Comment: I have now added the bit that was missing.

Comment: At some point before you print to the file, you will simply have to prefix the header string to the `s` variable.  Then print the file. It is that easy. But nothing in your question, nor in your code, explains how you would like to formulate the header string.  Now that you know *what* to do, do you think you can do it?

Comment: Thanks I just want to write a string like Time, Number 1, Number 2, etc

Comment: OK, so assuming it's tab-delimited (modify if needed) something like `header = "Time" & vbTab & "Number1" & vbTab & "Number2" & vbTab & ...` etc., and then: `s = header & vbCRLF & s`, then print to file.

Comment: Ok I will try this tomorrow makes sense, thanks for helping will let you know it goes

Comment: thank you for your help that worked a treat, I amended it so I only printed the header once!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help you out :)

Comment: David if you put what you said as the answer I can then tick you gave the right answer.

Comment: Cheers, I added an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point before you print to the file, you will simply have to prefix the header string to the `s` variable. Then print the file. It is that easy

Assuming it's tab-delimited (modify if needed) something like this will create a header string:

```
Dim header as String
header = "Time" & vbTab & "Number1" & vbTab & "Number2" & vbTab & ...
```

Then, before you print to file, prefix the header string to the `s` (which contains the full file text), separating with a Line Feed:

```
s = header & vbCRLF & s
```

Now, the `s` variable should contain the header string and the rest of the file text, so you can use your normal I/O print statement to write the fule.